SearchView expanded back button color
I have a fragment with Dark action bar (so white text and icon color)
im using the following menu item to create a searchview on click
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_toolbar_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

</menu>

How to change the color of the back icon only when the searchView is expanded. By default the back icon color should have back icon with OnPrimary color.

Note :
-> App's theme : Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
-> This is being done in a fragment &  background color is being changed using the following method:
activity.supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(getColor(activity, R.color.surface)))

